# Change image on WPF DataGrid column depending on value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I currently have a `DataGrid` within my application which uses dapper to fill its items source from a table within SQLServer. Within the table there is a `bool`/`bit` value which denotes whether the row has a hyperlink string or not. How can I change the image for each row to display a .png image of a hyperlink symbol is the value is `true` or display a cross if the symbol is `false`?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding documentID}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding documentTitle}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="TITLE" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a style for the `Image` in your column that sets its `Source` property to the corresponding PNG file depending on the `bool` property from your table, here `IsHyperlink`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataBaseTableSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="HyperlinkImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Setter Property="Source" Value="cross_symbol.png"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHyperlink}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="hyperlink_symbol.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="HyperLinkImageColumnTemplate">
         <Image Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkImageStyle}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding documentID}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding documentTitle}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="TITLE" IsReadOnly="True"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" CellTemplate="{StaticResource HyperLinkImageColumnTemplate}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Since you did not provide any file paths for the PNG images, you have to adapt them in the style.

Comment: Perfect that has done the job nice! Thank you